# How to declare a method parameter in c# as being of a concrete class and interface

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to write a method that accepts a parameter that is a Frame. In pseudo c#

```
public void Foo(FrameworkElement and ISomeInterface p){
    ...
}
```

Is this possible? It would have to work with a class defined so

```
public class MyGrid : Grid, ISomeInterface {
}
```

where it is known that Grid is a subclass of FrameworkElement

Answer (score 4):

You can create a generic method that enforces those constraints:

```
public void Foo<T>(T p) 
    where T : FrameworkElement, ISomeInterface
```

so here you're saying that the `Type` of the object passed in needs to be a `FrameworkElement` and implement `ISomeInterface`.